# What does "channel disagreement" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I am watching [Startup Funding Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=677ZtSMr4-4) on Youtube. he spoke the word channel disagreement at 41 second. I looked up both the words "channel" and "disagreement." I am still not sure. could someone explain them?

> It all starts with a vision. The project, the product, the service. No one has done it before. Unbelievable, it's so painfully obvious. Can you pull it off? Maybe. You're two friends, you're excited. Design a logo, design a name. All fun and games. Design a concept, things get serious. You decide to make this a company. You need a structure, a legal structure. How much will that cost you? In the U.S., incorporating a company will set you back anything between $25 and a few thousand dollars. That's in part registration fees, which actually vary depending on where you are and legal fees, which vary depending on how fancy you need your first **channel disagreement** to be. Your incorporation turns out to be on the pricey side. Also you need to rent a server in order to develop your product, therefore you decide to collect some other people's money for it. This earning your venture, who on earth would give you their money?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the string 'channel disagreement' is a misapprehension, not actually the words spoken. / Interpretation (even from quasi-English to English) of spoken texts is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just that guy's foreign accent.  He actually says:  **your first shareholders' agreement**

Answer (score 0):

I guess that he's referring to `Channel conflict`.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_conflict), "Channel conflict occurs when manufacturers (brands) disintermediate their channel partners, such as distributors, retailers, dealers, and sales representatives, by selling their products directly to consumers through general marketing methods and/or over the Internet."

In this context, it would mean that when you're setting up a business, deciding which channel to sell your product through can lead to legal expenditures.

Comment: No. See GEdgar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here **disagreement** refers to conflicts.

> Channel conflicts refer to disagreement among channel members over
>   goals, roles, and rewards.

This is more of a marketing term I guess. You might want to read more about it in a [general way](https://www.marketing91.com/types-channel-conflicts/).

Comment: No. See GEdgar's answer.